# Input.location.isEnabledByUser always return FALSE in GalaxyS8

Tags: unity-game-engine

In Unity app who run on Samsung Galaxy S8, Input.location.isEnabledByUser always return FALSE.
I have tried switching Location Services on and off to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the problem is with Galaxy S8 devices.
I have tried to run the same code on Huawei P8 and Input.location.isEnabledByUser return TRUE when Location Services is enabled, and FALSE when Location Services is disabled.
As it should.